# Magento, how to change PayPal/Express/Review page

Tags: magento

In my Magento web site, on the Review page of PayPal Express, the user needs to choose a shipping method.

My website has only one shipping Method which is "Free Shipping".

How can i make the "Free Shipping" be selected as default?

Answer (score 0):

below code is working great

```
<?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>

    //  add checking for free shipping method and setting it as default
    <?php if ($_rate->getCode()=='freeshipping_freeshipping' && !$this->getAddress()->getShippingMethod()) {
        $this->getAddress()->setShippingMethod($_rate->getCode());
    }
```

you can detail information on below reference
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/9223/#t33602

or you can refer:
[How to auto fill shipping method Magento for onepagechekout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451810/how-to-auto-fill-shipping-method-magento-for-onepagechekout)